# How does web server(IIS)detect user client IP of packet in network layer?

Tags: networking, ip, packet

I have a web server that can receive the client IP by http request headers in application layer.But if IP information don't exist in http headers.How can I know the client IP in network layer? For Example,to install networking software or hardware to detect source IP and pass it to my server.

Comment: By "Client IP", if you mean the address where the HTTP request originated, and if there's a possibility of HTTP requests reaching your web server via proxies (very likely if it's facing the Internet), then using TCP socket address might not always give you the originating address. See my answer for such a scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every accepted TCP socket can supply its remote IP address and remote port number, via the `getsockname()` API.

I think you'll find that your IIS is already doing that. Client IP isn't normally provided in the HTTP headers. It would be redundant.

Answer (score 1):

If "Client IP" refers to the address where the HTTP request originated, and not the last proxy that relayed the request to the web server, then it's more reliable to use the HTTP header convention. See [X-Forwarded-For](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For)